# Anypoint Studio 5.1.1 with empty properties view

Tags: java, eclipse, mule, eclipse-classpath

I am running the new Version of AnypointStudio for `win 64bit-5.1.0-201503171252` on a Windows 8.1 with Java 8.

If I click on a Element in the flow, I will see only:

[image: a empty property view].

I check the Eclipse Logfile (`AnypointStudio\workspace\.metadata\.log`) and find this error:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 2 2015-04-09 19:42:58.236
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/mule/tooling/apikit/common/metadata/resolver/APIkitRouterInvokerMetadataResolver$1$1
at org.mule.tooling.apikit.common.metadata.resolver.APIkitRouterInvokerMetadataResolver$1.call(APIkitRouterInvokerMetadataResolver.java:65)
at org.mule.tooling.apikit.common.metadata.resolver.APIkitRouterInvokerMetadataResolver$1.call(APIkitRouterInvokerMetadataResolver.java:1)
at org.mule.tooling.utils.SilentRunner.run(SilentRunner.java:16)
```

I try this on different Workstation with the same error.
I search the missing class and found this file in the plugin folder:

```
AnypointStudio-for-win-64bit-5.1.0-201503171252\AnypointStudio\plugins\org.mule.tooling.apikit.common_1.6.1.201503121950\org\mule\tooling\apikit\common\metadata\resolver\APIkitRouterInvokerMetadataResolver$1$1.class
```

Comment: Can you try removing the apikit plugin version 1.6.1 and check whether the UI issue is resolved. HTH.

Comment: Yes i removed the apikit plugin 1.6.1 and still have the problem. if i remove also the apikit 1.5.2. the problem is fixed. but the i woun't have any apikit plugin in my studio.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried removing the older APIKit plugin and only installing the latest? It could be a conflict between the different versions. 
HTH, 
Eva